# How to delete \shortitle from page when having footnote?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, titles

I have a document, where one page has two footnotes, but they are appearing just above `\shortitle` ... Can I force `\shortitle` to not appear on this particular page? Some pages have author and shortitle, some have only page numbers...

edit:
here goes beginnning of the document

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,12pt]{aghdpl}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% additional packages
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,bf}]{caption}
\lstloadlanguages{TeX}
```

then I have all info on supervisor, author, shorttitle, title, departments etc. This is needed for `\titlepages`. This is my bachelor of science thesis.

Then I have:

```
\begin{document}

\titlepages

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\include{rozdzial1}
\include{rozdzial2}
\include{rozdzial3}
\include{rozdzial4}
\include{rozdzial5}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
...
\end{thebibliography}
\include{rozdzial7}
\end{document}
```

And every time I need footnote I simply was using `\footnote{}`
I hope it is enough, isn't it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: now I suspect, that because it is custom document from my university you may not be able to tell how to change i.e. \shortitle{}

Comment: I found the class [on the internet](https://www.assembla.com/code/jcr-bc/subversion/nodes/docs/aghdpl/praca.pdf?rev=147). I won't discuss whether I like the idea of works title in the footer or not. I think you should not change it for one page and you better accept the fact that the result won't be really visually appealing on that page.

Comment: thank you very much :) if you post it I'll accept this as an aswer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be consistent and not to modify the page headers and footers only because footnotes are present. Since [the class](https://www.assembla.com/code/jcr-bc/subversion/nodes/docs/aghdpl/praca.pdf?rev=147) has a longer text and seperation line already in the footer, the result might not be exactly visually appealing, but consistency is more important.

You can try how the result looks like if the footnoteline is not present. This can be achieved by putting the following line into your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
```